# How can I remove html tags from text while predicting named entities with Spacy NER and again display the same text in original format with html tags?

Tags: html, regex, python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm using Spacy NER to recognize named entities from text but I have whole HTML page as input so how can I remove all the html tags from text and only give raw text without html tags to NER model for prediction and after prediction how can I show same text with HTML tags?

I tried xml.etree.ElementTree to remove HTML tags, this gives me text without html tags, but after prediction how can I display this text with all html tags in original format.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

def remove_html_tags(text):
    """Remove html tags from a string"""
    return ''.join(xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(text).itertext())
```

Is there any way that I can again display this text with original html tags or Spacy has any feature to ignore html tags while prediction of named entities ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is lazy way but you can save first condition of your html page somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @asdsfa for the answer and yes I can do that but not in real time because html pages has high variability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think spacy has a functionality like that... but you could save the xml ElementTree and just pass the text in to spacy... some version of:

```
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(text)

doc = nlp(root.itertext())
```

Comment: yes I'm giving the text to the nlp engine but after getting prediction, putting text again between appropriate html tags is difficult, because sometimes there tags between text also like <b> or <li>.